# How to call private virtual base class implementation when overriding in child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have a class  hierarchy like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
  void start() { init(); }
private:
  virtual void init() = 0;
};

class Default : public Base
{
private:
  virtual void init() override {/*default implementation*/};
};

class Special : public Default
{
private:
  virtual void init() override final {/*specialized implementation*/};
}
```

Which works alright if I call `start()` on an object of type `Special`;

Now I have a case where in the implementation in the `Special` class I want to call the implementation of the `Default` class.
Normally that would work with `Default::init();`, but will fail here due to the `Default`s declaration of this is `private`.

Obviously one solution is to change this from `private` to `protected`, but I'd like to ask if there is another way? Rather than allowing any child to call this function directly, I'd like to limit this to calls that are initiated via virtual functions already defined in the `Base` or `Default` class.

Is there some option or modifier that would allow member function calls to be only allowed from child classes if they are within (the same) overriding virtual member functions?

Comment: I think no, it's impossible. It's exactly usage of `protected`, allow to access from a child with `public` inheritance

Comment: The only think I can think of is to make the derived class `friend`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I'd qualify `friend` as more evil than `protected` in this case; it will allow access to possibly much more and would require to modify the base class with every new deriving class needing similar access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't provide means to achieve this directly, so you'd have to work around, e. g. in piece of code below.

Well, if you *absolutely want to*. I personally would rather just fall back to making the functions protected, *document* what they are intended for and when to be called, and then just trust the deriving classes to do the stuff right. That in the end keeps the interfaces cleaner and doesn't rely on a rather unusual (and perhaps ugly) pattern (actually passing `this` twice).

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { }
    void start()
    {
        InitProxy p(*this);
        init(p);
    }
protected:
    class InitProxy
    {
    public:
        InitProxy(InitProxy const&) = delete;
        void init()
        {
            m_base.Base::init(*this);
        }
    private:
        friend class Base;
        Base& m_base;
        InitProxy(Base& base)
            : m_base(base)
        { }
    };
private:
    virtual void init(InitProxy& proxy) { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    void init(InitProxy& proxy) override
    {
        proxy.init();
    }
};
```

You could let the proxy accept a member function pointer, if you want to apply this constraint to more than one function, so you wouldn't have to re-write the proxy for every function separately. Possibly you'd need to make a template from then, if function parameters differ.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare `Special`, and make it a friend of `Default`:

```
class Base
{
public:
  void start() { init(); }
private:
  virtual void init() = 0;
};

class Special;  // Forward declaration
class Default : public Base
{
private:
  virtual void init() override {/*default implementation*/}
  friend class Special; // Friend declaration
};

class Special : public Default
{
private:
  virtual void init() override final {
      Default::init();
      /*Other implementation*/
  }
};
```

Comment: Yet `friend` is evil.